# Unable to get 1000 Mbps of Internet in a network card that supports it

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I bought a new computer, I do not quite understand it. I bought a computer that supports 5G. I have a Qualcomm QCA61x4a 802.11ac wireless adapter driver network card. At home I have a 5G internet of 1000 Mbps.

I do not know why I get 5G, but the maximum speed I can get is 250 Mbps. I tried to connect a cable, but the maximum speed is 280 Mbps, what can I do. I do not understand that.

Comment: 5G means fifth-generation cell phone technology. Computers with 5G support are extremely rare. Did you instead mean "5GHz Wi-Fi"?

Comment: “5G internet of 1000MB” None of this makes sense. Do you mean you have 5G from a Mi-Fi hotspot? And the promised speed is 1000 Mbps speed?  @Spiff To me this reads that the original poster has some kind of Mi-Fi connection to 5G, but the device also has a Wi-Fi router. And the new computer connecting to that router is not getting 802.11ac speeds of 433 Mps to 1000 Mbps but something slower. 80211n should go up to 300 Mpbs so that seems to make sense.

Comment: @masterHaham How are you connecting to a 5G network? Do you know the make and model number of the device? It seems like your device is only capable of 802.11n speeds despite it connecting to a 5G network.

Comment: thank you for help, i'm dont really understand this subjectvery well, im sorry.
i mean that i have 1000 mbps internet that works on 5ghz. i have computer with "802.11ac" that support 1000 mbps, but i dont get it, even if i connent the computer with the cable. what can i do to get more mbps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Answer assumes that when you wrote "5G", you meant "5GHz Wi-Fi", not "fifth-generation cellular data".]

If your Qualcomm QCA61**x**4a is specifically a QCA61**7**4A (that's the only specific model I can easily find specs for online), then it's an 80MHz 2x2 AC design, meaning it has a top signaling rate (a.k.a. "PHY rate") of 867Mbps, resulting in top real world speeds of perhaps 600Mbps.

So if your Wi-Fi AP (that is, your wireless router) also supports AC with 80MHz-wide channels and 2x2 MIMO, and you have it on a clean 5GHz channel, and your client is close, but not too close, to the AP, then you should be able to see 600Mbps throughput.

Wi-Fi performance depends on the Wi-Fi specs of both the AP and the client device, and which of Wi-Fi's optional "go faster" features they **both** support.

If you're paying for residential broadband Internet service of 1Gbps and want to get full 1Gbps rates over the Wi-Fi in your home, then you need to make sure that both your AP and your client device support at least AC, 160MHz-wide channels, and at least 2x2 MIMO.

AC devices that support 160MHz-wide channels are uncommon but not impossible to find. It's more common to find AX (Wi-Fi 6) devices that support 160MHz-wide channels and at least 2x2 MIMO. Beware, though, that there aren't make 160MHz-wide channels to go around right now (until Wi-Fi 6E opens up the 6GHz band), so unless you live somewhere where the 5GHz airwaves aren't too crowded, you might not have a good way to get full 1Gbps speeds over Wi-Fi.

So when you want full 1Gbps speeds, you might need to connect an Ethernet cable between your router and your client, instead of using Wi-Fi. And by the way, 1Gbps Ethernet has some protocol overhead, so the theoretical max speed is about 943Mbps. Some high-end home gateway routers now have 10Gbps Ethernet ports, or even the ability to do a nonstandard 2.5Gbps mode that several vendors support, so if you want to eke out that last 6% of performance, you'll need to go with something high-end that supports faster than 1Gbps Ethernet.

Comment: Also, all devices must allow an internal processing power of the same speed. I once had a switch in the mix that did not have a fast processor and thus had lower speeds than the network ports that were attached. I plugged the cable in, the speed said 1Gbps, but the device itself capped lower.

Comment: My AP supports AC, and so does my new computer. But when I connected my computer via ethernet I get no more than 280 mbps. What can I do?

Comment: @masterHaham Call your ISP for tech support. They're not providing the speed of service you're paying for.

Comment: thank you for help, how can i know if my computer support 160MHz-wide channels or only 80MHz?

Comment: @masterHaham To find out if your card supports 160MHz-wide channels, find out exactly which wireless module/chipset you have (note: the "x" in the model number you gave is a variable; you need to find out exactly which number goes there), and look up its specifications.